# Multiple foreach loops

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'd like to have 2 foreach loops for 2 arrays like that, I know it's wrong:

$properties has 6 items and $set_properties has 11 items

```
<?php if(!empty($properties)) : foreach ($properties as $prop) : ?>
<?php if(!empty($set_properties)) : foreach ($set_properties as $set_prop) : ?>

<?php endforeach; endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; endif; ?>
```

What would be the right way, because right now I'm getting too many loops if I want to echo something out (`$prop->ID`).

My goal is to make dropdown selectors(`$properties`) and have `$set_properties` as options.

Comment: What you have here is correct, I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: So you should end up with 6 dropdowns with 11 options each?

Comment: Basically yes. 6 dropdowns and have options for them. With my example 11 options each, but I will separate those options later: so dropdown 1 has 2 options with specific ID's from $set_properties etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following snippet, which I commented to hopefully help you understand.

```
//check if properties is empty, if not, loop through them.
if(!empty($properties)): 
    foreach ($properties as $prop):

        //check if $set_properties is empty, if not create select element 
        if(!empty($set_properties)): 

            //loop through properties, generate select element for current index
            //obviously you can do proper select element naming and everything I just don't know your markup
            //notice I do this after checking if the options fields are empty, so that way it only appears if there are options associated with it.
            echo $prop->ID.": <select>";

            //loop through set_properties, generate options
            foreach ($set_properties as $set_prop):
                echo "<option value='{$set_prop->ID}'>{$set_prop->Name}</option>";
            endforeach;

            //end select element, so next iteration will make a new one.
            //again, inside the check for $set_properties because the select element will only exist if options exist
            echo "</select>";

        endif;

    endforeach; 
endif;
```

In your original code you switch in and out of PHP very often, and that is really not necessary, it makes the code look messy and it's harder to format. Just write it all in PHP as there isn't much HTML that goes into it. You should only switch in/out of PHP if you are only trying to insert a variable into an element, or if there is a lot of HTML.

Comment: Thank You! This looks much better and is easier to understand.

Comment: @Kaarel Glad that I could help!